# Vertical Centering Content inside Scrollview

Tags: ios, authentication, scrollview, swiftui

I'm trying to code a simple login page on my app. I started using SwiftUI on my newly updated macOS Catalina. The Apple documentation is still lacking a lot.
I need to center a VStack vertically on a Scrollview occupying the whole page with a "limit" on it's width of 400.

Something like this:

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: 400, alignment: .center)
}
```

It was easy with UIScrollView, just needed to set the ContentView to fill height and width and then centering a Vertical StackLayout inside the Content View but now with SwiftUI I just wonder.

The goal is something like this (Credit to the author)

[image]

If someone is wondering why I want everything inside a scrollview, it's because my form is quite big and I expect the user to use both landscape and portrait view so I really need the content to be scrollable. Bear in mind also that in an iPad, the form doesn't fill the whole screen, that's why I want it centered vertically.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

### iOS 17+

As of iOS 17, you can achieve this without a `GeometryReader` by using `containerRelativeFrame` to reserve space in a `ZStack`.

As a bonus you can also disable scroll bouncing with `.scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize)`.

```swift
ScrollView {
    ZStack {
        // Reserve space matching the scroll view's frame
        Spacer().containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical])

        // Form content
        VStack {
            Text("Form goes here")
        }
        // Set your max width (optional)
        .frame(maxWidth: 400)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
// Disable bounce if the content fits (optional)
.scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize)
```

### iOS 13+

You can vertically center content in a scroll view by using `GeometryReader` to get the parent view's dimensions and setting the scroll view's content's `minHeight` to the parent's height.

When the content is too big to fit vertically it'll just scroll like normal.

For example:

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            // Form content
            VStack {
                Text("Form goes here")
            }
            // Set your max width (optional)
            .frame(maxWidth: 400)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.yellow)

            // Make the scroll view full-width
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width) 

            // Set the content’s min height to the parent
            .frame(minHeight: geometry.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: Thanks Alex, that helped with a very simple approach :)

Comment: Best solution for this case

Answer (score 32):

I've build a more generic view based on @Alex answer

```swift
/// Custom vertical scroll view with centered content vertically
///
struct VScrollView<Content>: View where Content: View {
  @ViewBuilder let content: Content
  
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      ScrollView(.vertical) {
        content
          .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
          .frame(minHeight: geometry.size.height)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use it anywhere in your app like this

```
  var body: some View {
    VScrollView {
      VStack {
        Text("YOUR TEXT HERE")
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would like to know why the ScrollView doesn't knows the height, I looked into the docs but can't find it, do you know it?