# Center and align SwiftUI elements in a ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following SwiftUI view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MySwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("top leading text")
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("centered text")
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("bottom trailing text")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this when run:

[image]

If I embed the view in a `ScrollView` like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MySwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("top leading text")
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("centered text")
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("bottom trailing text")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then it looks like this when run:

[image]

How do I make the centered text centered, and the bottom trailing text rest on the bottom, when they are embedded in a `ScrollView`?

In a way, I want to use SwiftUI to replicate this scrolling behaviour seen in Xcode's inspectors, where the text "Not Applicable" is centered and scrollable:

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wrap the ScrollView inside `GeometryReader`. Then apply a minimum height to the scroll view equal to the `geometry.size.height`. Now the spacers you applied should fill the VStack the way you intended them to. Try the code below:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("top leading text")
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text("centered text")
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                Spacer()
                Text("bottom trailing text")
            }
         }
         .padding()
         .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
         .frame(minHeight: geometry.size.height)

    }
}
```

Also check this post for more discussion on this issue: [SwiftUI - Vertical Centering Content inside Scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122998/swiftui-vertical-centering-content-inside-scrollview)

Comment: What if ScrollView does not fill the entire height of the screen? For example, if it's inside the VStack with some view above it? Then using geometry height would be too high.

Comment: @DamianDudycz here's a Gist I made that presents a ScrollView inside a VStack. The trick is to place the outer VStack outside of the GeometryReader with views above and below the GeometryReader:  https://gist.github.com/SevanBadal/70c38699f1a5f7596114415661c7f9ca